# Trying to extract data from several thousand JSON files in Java with schema deviations

Tags: java, arrays, json, data-mining

I've got several thousand JSON files. Most of them can have a single JSON array with as many as 10,000 elements inside the array ... and to make things even more interesting, the data structure of the elements can vary from element to element ... sometimes with just a simple single property deviation from the norm to deviations that add even more arrays within each element. But it's this "items" array that I need to extract from each of these files.

The method of attack on this problem - in my logic that is - is to first extract each of the different data structures from all of the files, so that I understand what I'm going after when I try to get the data. If I can't name the elements that I want, then how could I get them? Though there might actually be a way of doing that, I'm just not knowledgeable enough on JSON and GSON, etc. to know one way or the other.

This will be my first real JSON project as well ... I've not ever played with JSON before so I've spent a lot of time Googling and reading and I definitely understand - NOW - how JSON works ... I'm just ill-equipped to wield it with any kind of effectiveness. I've spent the last couple of days on these files, and although I've gained some ground, I'm smart enough to know when I've gotten to the point where I need some help from people who have done this before.

These examples are not cut and paste from these files. I made them generic for simplicity. But here is what I've seen so far as an example of the differences in structures from one file to the next. The first file is by far the most common ... where the "items" array will have that static structure with the exact same element names but there will be 10,000 of them within a file ... while the next file won't be so clean.

Most common JSON file that I am seeing among these files:

```
{
  "employees" : [
    {
      "name": "John Doe"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jane Doe"
    }
  ],
  "items": [
    {
      "item_name": "Goofy Widget",
      "timestamp": 1616987224024,
      "contents": "Some really nice goofy widgets",
      "item_type": "Cleaning Widget",
      "for_sale": false
    },
    {
      "item_name": "Machine Widget",
      "timestamp": 1616987218652,
      "contents": "Hand held vaccuum",
      "item_type": "Functional Widget",
      "for_sale": false
    }
  ],
  "items_from_inventory": true,
  "category_type": "Average",
  "region_placement": "Northwest America"
}
```

And having manually looked over several files, some can look like this, where there is deviation sometimes from one complete array element to the next:

```
{
  "employees" : [
    {
      "name": "Jack Smith"
    },
    {
      "name": "Joe Smith"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jimmy Smalley"
    }
  ],
  "items": [
    {
      "item_name": "Sneakers",
      "timestamp": 1616987224024,
      "contents": "Plain white sneakers",
      "item_type": "Foot Wear",
      "for_sale": false
    },
    {
      "item_name": "Personal T-Shirts",
      "timestamp": 1616987224024,
      "contents": "Color variety T-Shirts",
      "color_options": [
        {
          "color1": "Red",
          "color2": "Green",
          "color3": "Black",
          "color4": "White"
        }
      ],
      "item_classifications": [
        {
          "class1": "Weekend Use",
          "class2": "Family Picnics",
          "class3": "Casual Fridays"
        },
      ],
      "for_sale": false
    },
    {
      "item_name": "Basketballs",
      "timestamp": 1616987218652,
      "contents": "Three quality basketballs",
      "item_type": "Sport Items",
      "brands": [
        {
        "brand1": ",Spalding",
        "brand2": "Wilson"
        },
      ],
      "for_sale": false
    }
  ],
  "items_from_inventory": false,
  "category_type": "Personal Use",
  "region_placement": "North America"
}
```

The basic core structure of these files are fairly consistent from one file to the next, the deviation seems to be mainly within the "items" array where some elements have a different data structure (schema as we know it in the MySql world) than others.

I've been mainly experimenting with GSON because it seems to be fairly popular, although I'm not concerned with what library(s) I use, I just need to get to the data.

I decided I'd start with targeting the most common array structure that I'm seeing so far, and this is what I came up with. Here is the class that represents the most common array structure:

```
package widgets;

public class Widget {
    
    public Widget(String itemName, long timestamp, String contents, String itemType, boolean forSale) {
        this.itemName     = itemName;
        this.timestamp    = timestamp;
        this.contents     = contents;
        this.itemType     = itemType;
        this.forSale      = forSale;
    }

    private String             itemName;
    private long               timestamp;
    private String             contents;
    private String             itemType;
    private boolean            forSale;

    public void setItemName(String itemName) { this.itemName = itemName;}

    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) { this.timestamp = timestamp;}

    public void setContents(String contents) { this.contents = contents;}

    public void setItemType(String itemType) { this.itemType = itemType;}

    public void setForSale(boolean forSale)  { this.forSale = forSale;}

    public String getItemName() { return itemName;}

    public long getTimestamp()  { return timestamp;}

    public String getContents() { return contents;}

    public String getItemType() { return itemType;}

    public boolean isForSale()  { return forSale;}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "senderName = " + this.itemName + "\n" +
               "timestamp = " + this.timestamp + "\n" +
               "content = " + this.contents + "\n" +
               "type = " + this.itemType + "\n" +
               "isUnsent = " + (this.forSale ? "true" : "false") + "\n";
    }
}
```

I kind of want to leave it right here and not really get into where I've succeeded and where I've failed because I don't really care about what I'm doing wrong, I just need to know how to do it right... so here is what I'm asking for:

Will someone show me how to extract all of the Json structure definitions from these files, including the different structures that can happen randomly within each "items" element?

And can someone show me how to properly extract the data given the fact that the structure of the "items" array can be different from one element to the next?

I just need someone who has been here before and can point me down the right path so that I don't have to walk each path, turn around and walk back then try another one.

I would be most grateful for the help.

Thank you,

Mike Sims

Comment: So "items" JSON Object will always be in the JSON directly (without any parent JSON node) ?

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri - Exactly like the sample file looks is exactly how my files look.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri The second JSON file example was incorrect. It was not syntactically exactly the same as my files here. I corrected it.

Comment: Yeah, I have pasted an answer. Give it a try.

Comment: Your task seems to be quite specific and I, personally, would write some custom code using event/token/stream-based API and I wouldn't use the object mapping at all. Both Gson and Jackson provide such type of API. You also can take a look at this tiny parser https://github.com/anatolygudkov/green-jelly The idea is simple - you receive some events and create new instance of your class, put a value to its field, put the result into final collection when ready. See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59041703/query-a-json-file-with-java-large-file/59179114#59179114

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have realized the power of GSON!

I ended up figuring out how to map JSON data to classes. I started by walking through all of the files and extracting each element name using a method like this:

```
private void getElements(String path){
        try {
            Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(path));
            JsonObject jo = JsonParser.parseReader(reader).getAsJsonObject();
            for (String key : jo.keySet()) {
                System.out.println(key);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Which ended up giving me:

```
employees
items
items_from_inventory
category_type
region_placement
```

Which I already knew, but the method allowed me to verify that each file was the same in terms of the master elements.

Then, knowing that items is an array, I again walked each file and used this method to get the elements from each array, only I decided instead of printing to console, I created an array list to hold each structure of each array only when that structure was unique:

```
private final List<LinkedList<String>> arraySets = new ArrayList<>();
private void getArrayElements(String path) {
    try {
        Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(path));
        JsonObject jo = JsonParser.parseReader(reader).getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray ja = jo.getAsJsonArray("items");
        int max = ja.size();
        for (int x = 0; x < max; x++) {
            JsonElement je = ja.set(x,ja.get(x));
            JsonObject njo = je.getAsJsonObject();
            LinkedList<String> arraySet = new LinkedList<>();
            for(String key: njo.keySet()) {
                arraySet.addLast(key);
            }
            if (!arraySets.contains(arraySet)) {
                arraySets.add(arraySet);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

In like manner, I went through each of the arrays within the array and extracted those element names.

Then, I created a master class that had variables that fit the outline of each file, since each file had the exact same elements in it - with the only difference of course being that each "items" array could have different elements within it.

So, the master class for the whole file looked something like this:

```
import Item;
import Employee;
import java.util.List;

public class Master {

    private List<Employee> employees;
    private List<Item>     items;
    private boolean items_from_inventory;
    private String category_type;
    private String region_placement;

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public boolean isItems_from_inventory() {
        return items_from_inventory;
    }

    public void setItems_from_inventory(boolean items_from_inventory) {
        this.items_from_inventory = items_from_inventory;
    }

    public String getCategory_type() {
        return category_type;
    }

    public void setCategory_type(String category_type) {
        this.category_type = category_type;
    }

    public String getRegion_placement() {
        return region_placement;
    }

    public void setRegion_placement(String region_placement) {
        this.region_placement = region_placement;
    }
}
```

Then the Employee class looked something like this:

```
public class Employee {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And the Items class was similar, only it had additional List variables and each list type was its own class that had the independent elements of the array that it was to be mapped to. I included all possible arrays that could be included in the items array.

Then I simply did this:

```
Path         rootDir  = Paths.get(rootFolderString);
Stream<Path> paths    = Files.walk(rootDir);
List<Path>   pathList = paths.collect(Collectors.toList());
for (Path path : pathList) {
    if (path.toFile().getAbsolutePath().endsWith("json")) {
        String fileString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path.toFile().getAbsolutePath()));
        Master master = new Gson().fromJson(fileString,new TypeToken<Master>() {}.getType());
    }
}
```

And it worked like a champ!

Answer (score 1):

To extract the JSON Array from JSON String, and then to convert JSONArray to Widget object you can do something like this:

```
JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(<full json string>);
JSONArray itemsArr = mainObj.getJSONArray("items");
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
List<Widget> widgetList = objectMapper.readValue(itemsArr.toString(), new 
TypeReference<List<Widget>>(){});
// work with widgetList here
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using something lighter weight and more interactive for your exploratory data analysis of the "shape" of the data. My two top choices would be:

- [OpenRefine](https://openrefine.org)
- [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Depending on whether you are more comfortable with an interactive graphical tool or a command line tool. Both are open source and free and will allow you to quickly explore your data set.