# Streaming large JSON from input stream efficiently in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

In order to save memory and avoid an OOM error, I want to stream a large JSON from an input stream and extract the desired things from it. More exactly, I want to extract and save some strings from that JSON:

1. files.content.fileContent.subList.text = "some text in file"
2. files.content.fileContent.subList.text = "some text in file2"

and save them into a String variable:

```
String result = "some text in file \r\nsome text in file2"
```

I tried to parse the JSON using Jackson:

```
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try (JsonParser jsonParser = jsonFactory.createParser(jsonAsInputStream)) {
            String fieldName;
            while (jsonParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
                jsonParser.nextToken();
                fieldName = jsonParser.getCurrentName();
                if ("files".equals(fieldName)) {

                    while (true) {
                        jsonParser.nextToken();
                        fieldName = jsonParser.getCurrentName();
                        if ("content".equals(fieldName)) {
                            jsonParser.nextToken();
                            fieldName = jsonParser.getCurrentName();
                            while (true) {
                                if ("text".equals(fieldName)) {
                                    result.append(jsonParser.getText());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            LOGGER.info("result: {}", result);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The above is not working at all, that solution gets complicated. Is there any simple way to parse the JSON inputStream and extract some text from it?

Below is the JSON attached:

```
{
"id": "1",
"name": "TestFile.xlsx",
"files": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "fileName": "TestFile.xlsx",
        "types": {
            "fileId": "1",
            "context": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "contextId": "xyz",
                    "metadata": {
                        "abc": "1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "contextId": "abc"
                }
            ],
            "fileSettings": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "settingId": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "settingId": 2
                }
                
            ],
            "fileAttachments": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "canDelete": true,
                    "canAttach": []
                }
            ],
            "replacements": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "replacementText": "xcv"
                }
            ]
        },
        "content": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "contextList": [
                    1,
                    2,
                    3
                ],
                "fileContent": {
                    "contentType": "text",
                    "subList": [
                        {
                            "id": "1",
                            "subList": [
                                {
                                    "id": "1",
                                    "text": "some text in file",
                                    "type": "text"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "externalContent": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": "1",
                            "contentType": "text corrupted",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "contextList": [
                    1,
                    2
                ],
                "fileContent": {
                    "contentType": "text",
                    "subList": [
                        {
                            "id": "2",
                            "subList": [
                                {
                                    "id": "1",
                                    "text": "some text in file2",
                                    "type": "text"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "externalContent": {
                    "id": "2",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": "2",
                            "contentType": "text corrupted2",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Have a look at [BSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON).

Comment: You are on the right way. The most efficient approach to process large files is to use Streaming APIs. You may take a look at an alternative library which doesn't require to iterate over tokens, but provides a set of callbacks instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59041703/query-a-json-file-with-java-large-file/59179114#59179114 Anyway, an efficient way usually means more complex way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short,

- your code does not work because it implements a wrong algorithm;
- JsonPath, as it has been suggested, seems to be a good DSL implementation, but it uses a DOM approach collecting entire JSON tree into memory, therefore you'll run into OOM again.

You have two solutions:

- implement a proper algorithm within your current approach (and I agree you were on a right way);
- try implementing something similar to what JsonPath implements breaking down the problem to smaller ones supporting really streaming approach.

I wouldn't document much of my code since it's pretty easy to understand and adapt to other libraries, but you can develop a more advanced thing of the following code using Java 17 (w/ preview features enabled) and `javax.json` (+ some Lombok for Java boilerplate):

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public final class PathJsonParser
        implements JsonParser, Iterator<JsonParser.Event> {

    private static final int DEFAULT_PATH_LENGTH = 32;

    private final JsonParser jsonParser;
    private final AbstractPathElement[] path;
    private int last;

    public static PathJsonParser create(final JsonParser jsonParser) {
        final int maxPathLength = DEFAULT_PATH_LENGTH;
        final PathJsonParser pathJsonParser = new PathJsonParser(jsonParser, new AbstractPathElement[maxPathLength]);
        pathJsonParser.path[0] = AbstractPathElement.Root.instance;
        for ( int i = 1; i < maxPathLength; i++ ) {
            pathJsonParser.path[i] = new AbstractPathElement.Container();
        }
        return pathJsonParser;
    }

    @Override
    public Event next() {
        final Event event = jsonParser.next();
        switch ( event ) {
        case START_ARRAY -> {
            path[last].tryIncreaseIndex();
            path[++last].reset(JsonValue.ValueType.ARRAY);
        }
        case START_OBJECT -> {
            path[last].tryIncreaseIndex();
            path[++last].reset(JsonValue.ValueType.OBJECT);
        }
        case KEY_NAME -> path[last].setKeyName(jsonParser.getString());
        case VALUE_STRING -> path[last].tryIncreaseIndex();
        case VALUE_NUMBER -> path[last].tryIncreaseIndex();
        case VALUE_TRUE -> path[last].tryIncreaseIndex();
        case VALUE_FALSE -> path[last].tryIncreaseIndex();
        case VALUE_NULL -> path[last].tryIncreaseIndex();
        case END_OBJECT -> --last;
        case END_ARRAY -> --last;
        default -> throw new AssertionError(event);
        }
        return event;
    }

    public boolean matchesRoot(final int at) {
        @Nullable
        final AbstractPathElement e = tryElementAt(at);
        return e != null && e.matchesRoot();
    }

    public boolean matchesIndex(final int at, final IntPredicate predicate) {
        @Nullable
        final AbstractPathElement e = tryElementAt(at);
        return e != null && e.matchesIndex(predicate);
    }

    public boolean matchesName(final int at, final Predicate<? super String> predicate) {
        @Nullable
        final AbstractPathElement e = tryElementAt(at);
        return e != null && e.matchesName(predicate);
    }

    // @formatter:off
    @Override public boolean hasNext() { return jsonParser.hasNext(); }
    @Override public String getString() { return jsonParser.getString(); }
    @Override public boolean isIntegralNumber() { return jsonParser.isIntegralNumber(); }
    @Override public int getInt() { return jsonParser.getInt(); }
    @Override public long getLong() { return jsonParser.getLong(); }
    @Override public BigDecimal getBigDecimal() { return jsonParser.getBigDecimal(); }
    @Override public JsonLocation getLocation() { return jsonParser.getLocation(); }
    @Override @SuppressWarnings("MethodDoesntCallSuperMethod") public JsonObject getObject() { return jsonParser.getObject(); }
    @Override @SuppressWarnings("MethodDoesntCallSuperMethod") public JsonValue getValue() { return jsonParser.getValue(); }
    @Override @SuppressWarnings("MethodDoesntCallSuperMethod") public JsonArray getArray() { return jsonParser.getArray(); }
    @Override @SuppressWarnings("MethodDoesntCallSuperMethod") public Stream<JsonValue> getArrayStream() { return jsonParser.getArrayStream(); }
    @Override @SuppressWarnings("MethodDoesntCallSuperMethod") public Stream<Map.Entry<String, JsonValue>> getObjectStream() { return jsonParser.getObjectStream(); }
    @Override @SuppressWarnings("MethodDoesntCallSuperMethod") public Stream<JsonValue> getValueStream() { return jsonParser.getValueStream(); }
    @Override @SuppressWarnings("MethodDoesntCallSuperMethod") public void skipArray() { jsonParser.skipArray(); }
    @Override @SuppressWarnings("MethodDoesntCallSuperMethod") public void skipObject() { jsonParser.skipObject(); }
    @Override public void close() { jsonParser.close(); }
    // @formatter:on

    @Nullable
    private AbstractPathElement tryElementAt(final int at) {
        final int pathAt;
        if ( at >= 0 ) {
            pathAt = at;
        } else {
            pathAt = last + at + 1;
        }
        if ( pathAt < 0 || pathAt > last ) {
            return null;
        }
        return path[pathAt];
    }

    private abstract static sealed class AbstractPathElement
            permits AbstractPathElement.Root, AbstractPathElement.Container {

        abstract void reset(JsonValue.ValueType valueType);

        abstract void setKeyName(String keyName);

        abstract void tryIncreaseIndex();

        abstract boolean matchesRoot();

        abstract boolean matchesIndex(IntPredicate predicate);

        abstract boolean matchesName(Predicate<? super String> predicate);

        @RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
        private static final class Root
                extends AbstractPathElement {

            private static final AbstractPathElement instance = new Root();

            @Override
            void reset(final JsonValue.ValueType valueType) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            @Override
            void setKeyName(final String keyName) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            @Override
            void tryIncreaseIndex() {
                // do nothing
            }

            @Override
            boolean matchesRoot() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            boolean matchesIndex(final IntPredicate predicate) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            boolean matchesName(final Predicate<? super String> predicate) {
                return false;
            }

        }

        @RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
        private static final class Container
                extends AbstractPathElement {

            private static final String NO_KEY_NAME = null;
            private static final int NO_INDEX = -1;

            private JsonValue.ValueType valueType;
            private String keyName = NO_KEY_NAME;
            private int index = NO_INDEX;

            @Override
            void reset(final JsonValue.ValueType valueType) {
                this.valueType = valueType;
                keyName = NO_KEY_NAME;
                index = NO_INDEX;
            }

            @Override
            void setKeyName(final String keyName) {
                this.keyName = keyName;
            }

            @Override
            void tryIncreaseIndex() {
                if ( valueType == JsonValue.ValueType.ARRAY ) {
                    index++;
                }
            }

            @Override
            boolean matchesRoot() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            boolean matchesIndex(final IntPredicate predicate) {
                return switch ( valueType ) {
                    case ARRAY -> index != NO_INDEX && predicate.test(index);
                    case OBJECT -> false;
                    case STRING, NUMBER, TRUE, FALSE, NULL -> throw new AssertionError(valueType);
                };
            }

            @Override
            boolean matchesName(final Predicate<? super String> predicate) {
                return switch ( valueType ) {
                    case ARRAY -> false;
                    case OBJECT -> !Objects.equals(keyName, NO_KEY_NAME) && predicate.test(keyName);
                    case STRING, NUMBER, TRUE, FALSE, NULL -> throw new AssertionError(valueType);
                };
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Example of use:

```java
public final class PathJsonParserTest {

    // $.files.0.content.0.fileContent.subList.0.subList.0.text
    private static boolean matches(final PathJsonParser parser) {
        return parser.matchesName(-1, name -> name.equals("text"))
                && parser.matchesIndex(-2, index -> true)
                && parser.matchesName(-3, name -> name.equals("subList"))
                && parser.matchesIndex(-4, index -> true)
                && parser.matchesName(-5, name -> name.equals("subList"))
                && parser.matchesName(-6, name -> name.equals("fileContent"))
                && parser.matchesIndex(-7, index -> true)
                && parser.matchesName(-8, name -> name.equals("content"))
                && parser.matchesIndex(-9, index -> true)
                && parser.matchesName(-10, name -> name.equals("files"))
                && parser.matchesRoot(-11);
    }

    @Test
    public void test()
            throws IOException {
        try ( final PathJsonParser parser = PathJsonParser.create(JsonParsers.openFromResource(PathJsonParserTest.class, "input.json")) ) {
            for ( ; parser.hasNext(); parser.next() ) {
                if ( matches(parser) ) {
                    parser.next();
                    System.out.println(parser.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Of course, not that cool-looking as JsonPath is, but you can do the following:

- implement a matcher builder API to make it look nicer;
- implement a JSON Path-compliant parser to build matchers;
- wrap the `for/if/next()` pattern into a generic algorithm (similar to what `BufferedReader.readLine()` implements or wrap it for Stream API);
- implement some kind of simple JSON-to-objects deserializer.

Or, if possible, find a good code generator that can generate a streamed parser having as small runtime cost as possible (its outcome would be very similar to yours, but working). (Ping me please if you are aware of any.)

Comment: your code looks very good - I'm trying to understand the code, I'm using java 11, I hope I can update the code to java 11 fashion in order to be able to run it.

Comment: @pcCC28 Thank you! Downgrading from Java 17 to Java 11 should be easy, I guess. However, please note that the parser implementation targets `javax.json` heavily considering some of its inconsistencies (note that the `JsonParser` provides the "on new object property name", but does not provide "on new array element index"), so adapting it to another library will definitely need fixes.

Comment: for my scenario the input would be an InputStream. Could this code be adapted to work with input stream as well?

Comment: @pcCC28 Sure. Open your `InputStream`, wrap it in `Reader` (using `InputStreamReader`, byte source to char source), then wrap it in `JsonParser` (using `Json.createParser(...)`, char source to JSON token source), and wrap the latter to `PathJsonParser`.

Comment: I'm getting "Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found":
        String jsonFilePath = "src/test/resources/test.json";
        File initialFile = new File(jsonFilePath);

        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(initialFile);
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        JsonParser parser2 = Json.createParser(reader);

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: nvm me - I think I don't have that library

Comment: @pcCC28 Yeah, because the implementation interfaces are supplied using service providers. Try to include this implementation to your build: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/javax.json/1.1.4 (adding the dependency reference to your `pom.xml` (or whatever you're using) should work just fine.)

Comment: I successfully ran the code on my localhost. I tried to parse a large json ~200MB. The process consumed 3GB of RAM roughly, it is very slow :(

Comment: @pcCC28 How long does it take? Did you probably try to measure which pieces of code run slow?

Comment: I run the unit test, same as from you example above. The operation took ~7 minutes, I monitored the RAM, the process consume more than 3GB.

Comment: Initially, I saved the response into a String object via concatentation. I switched to StringBuilder and it seems faster.

Comment: @pcCC28 Indeed, terribly slow, but it does not crash with OOM now right? I only ran it for the JSON snippet you provided in the question. Please try narrowing down the slowest methods using stopwatches or profiling tools (not sure why it took 3GB, I guess it comes from the JSON parser implementation), or try experimenting with another library if the GlassFish JSON parser is really that slow. Also, please consider using `jq` to extract the data and get the time `jq` takes (just wondering how long it would take).

Comment: @pcCC28 Ah, okay, `String.concat` performance sucks, that's true. You can also try collect all strings to a list, then, once the parsing is done, sum all string lengths to their grand total, create a `StringBuilder` with the calcualted capacity and then append the strings to it. I believe it should be even faster. Or, if possible, simply write the strings to your target without buffering those to a single string (still have no idea why you need to a collect a single string out of it).

Comment: I will try and monitor the memory.

Comment: @pcCC28 I'll probably move my comments as the answer updates, because S.O. is warning about the extended discussions here. Just wondering: how long does it take for you to read the JSON document now (comparing to horribly slow 7 minutes you mentioned because of a to-string buffering)? Did you probably switched from buffering and simply write the filtered output directly somewhere (say, another output stream)? Did you try comparing it to `jq`? Thanks.

Comment: Now, it took ~90 seconds.

Comment: I found a JSON that contains more than 2 "subList" fields.
e.g subList -> subList -> subList -> subList -> ... -> text.
Is there any possibility to include this scenario in the "matches" method?

Comment: do you have any idea @user12232870?

Comment: Mate I spent my spare personal time to implement it trying to make it fast and as clean as possible to make it extendable. Take a look how the "matches" method works and try to add another predicate. It's **super** easy. I'm not a personal tutor for free, sorry.

Comment: totally agreed! Thanks a lot, Initially a tried to add a predicate but it didn't work, that's why I asked again if it's possible. I will look deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)? You can use Gson or Jackson as a provider, but by default, it uses Json-smart, which is performance-focused.

Here is an example based on your attached JSON.

```
InputStream inputStream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.json");
String[] textArray = JsonPath.parse(inputStream).read("files[*].content[*].fileContent.subList[*].subList[*].text", String[].class);
Arrays.stream(textArray).forEach(System.out::println);
```

JsonPath gonna use a lot of memory. If you don't have enough memory to handle large files, you can use a stream/token approach. The code below could handle json files of 6GB with 900MB of Heap or less if you don't store texts.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    try (InputStream inputStream = getJsonAsInputStream()) {
        EnumMap<JsonToken, JsonTokenHandler> map = getJsonTokenHandler();

        Context context = new Context();
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        while (true) {
            JsonToken token = reader.peek();
            JsonTokenHandler jsonTokenHandler = map.get(token);
            jsonTokenHandler.handle(reader, context);
            if (token.equals(END_DOCUMENT)) {
                break;
            }
        }

        context.getTexts().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

private static EnumMap<JsonToken, JsonTokenHandler> getJsonTokenHandler() {
    EnumMap<JsonToken, JsonTokenHandler> map = new EnumMap<>(JsonToken.class);
    map.put(BEGIN_ARRAY, (reader, context) -> reader.beginArray());
    map.put(END_ARRAY, (reader, context) -> reader.endArray());
    map.put(BEGIN_OBJECT, (reader, context) -> reader.beginObject());
    map.put(END_OBJECT, (reader, context) -> reader.endObject());
    map.put(NAME, (reader, context) -> {
        reader.nextName();
        context.setCurrentPath(reader.getPath());
    });
    map.put(STRING, (reader, context) -> {
        String string = reader.nextString();
        if (context.isTextAttribute()) {
            context.addText(string);
        }

    });
    map.put(NUMBER, (reader, context) -> reader.nextString());
    map.put(BOOLEAN, (reader, context) -> reader.nextBoolean());
    map.put(NULL, (reader, context) -> reader.nextNull());
    map.put(END_DOCUMENT, (reader, context) -> {
    });
    return map;
}

private static InputStream getJsonAsInputStream() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File inFile = new File("/path/to/your/large/file.json");
    ReadableByteChannel rChannel = new RandomAccessFile(inFile, "r").getChannel();
    return Channels.newInputStream(rChannel);
}


static class Context {
    private String currentPath;
    private List<String> texts = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addText(String text) {
        texts.add(text);
    }

    public List<String> getTexts() {
        return texts;
    }

    public void setCurrentPath(String path) {
        this.currentPath = path;
    }

    public boolean isTextAttribute() {
        return currentPath.matches("\\$\\.files\\[\\d+\\]\\.content\\[\\d+\\]\\.fileContent\\.subList\\[\\d+\\]\\.subList\\[\\d+\\]\\.text");
    }
}

interface JsonTokenHandler {
    void handle(JsonReader reader, Context context) throws IOException;
}
```

}

Comment: What is the performance impact on using JsonPath for really large files?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a really easy solution to your problem.
You can use Jackson "JsonParser" to stream your objects and ObjectMapper to parse them without re-writing the parsing logic.

This would look like this :

```
try (JsonParser jsonParser = objectMapper.getFactory().createParser(inputStreamReader)) {
  if (jsonParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Expected content to be an array");
  }

  while (jsonParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
    MyObject myObject = objectMapper.readValue(jsonParser, MyObject.class);
    log.info("This is my object: {}", myObject);
  }
}
```

If each of your object are small enough (which is the case most of the time) you can handle easily files with GB of data. And it is not specific to your case.

Only catch is this will not work if one of your object is huge.

I hope it helps someone.